# Getting image information from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

this may be a pretty basic questions, i'm trying to get the image info from the input field.

form.html -

```
<form id="file-form" action="handler.php" method="POST">
  <input type="file" id="file-select" name="image" multiple/>
  <input type="text" id="text-input" />
  <button type="submit" id="upload-button">Upload</button>
</form>
```

And in my js file, i've searched for the input field by using id.

upload.js -

```
var fileSelect = jQuery('#file-select');
```

I would like to find why by using

```
var file = fileSelect[0].files
```

I'm able to get the file information whereas doing

```
var file = fileSelect.files
```

returns 'undefined.' yet doing

```
jQuery('#text-input').val();
```

actually returns value even though I did not include any index value

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: fileSelect is an array.  use console.log or run your code in your browser's debug console to inspect its values.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//$("input[type=file]") always returns the array of files .
 
    $("input[type=file]").on("change",function(e){
    var  type= this.files[0].type;//0 indicate first file in list 
    var name =this.files[0].name;
    var size=this.files[0].size;
    var lastlastModifiedDate=this.files[0].lastModifiedDate;
      alert("type:"+type+"\n name:"+name+"\nsize:"+size);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
```

Answer (score 0):

`fileSelect` is a jQuery object, which doesn't have `files` property.

`files` is a property of the native dom element, you have to get the native dom element first from the jQuery object, then access the `files` property.